# How to utilize mersenne twister to get evenly distributed int in the range of [0,n] from random unsigned 32-bit integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, mersenne-twister

My Mersenne twister returns a random unsigned 32-bit integer.

I want to get evenly distributed random integer number in [0,n]

How can I convert this output from twister to this?

Comment: Or maybe [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range).

Comment: Can n be larger than 32 bits?

Comment: n will be in my case not larger than 1000

Comment: Also, in the solution linked, the crypto library is populating the byteArray. How can I populate byte array from unsigned int 32?